# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str when trying to calculate new records in several fields

Tags: arcpy, cursor, typeerror

I am trying to calculate new records in several fields by looping through each field in a list and dividing the value of each record by its shape area. My code is as follows:

```
inFeature = outFeature
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
divfield = "Shape_Area"

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(inFeature, my_list) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        for n in range(len(my_list)):
            row[n] = row[n] / row[divfield]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

I am getting the error: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

All of my fields are stored as double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List indices must be integers, not strings.

Where you use `row[divfield]` you are trying to use "Shape_Area" (the value of `divfield`), which is a string, as a list index.

You have opened your cursor with three fields 'a', 'b' and 'c' which you can refer to the values of using row[0], row[1] and row[2] respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using and it worked out:

```
inFeature = outFeature
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'Shape_Area']
divfield = len(my_list) - 1

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(inFeature, my_list) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        for n in range(len(my_list)):
            row[n] = row[n] / row[divfield]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```